# How do you Iterate over a List of objects in Dart to a details page in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, podo

When I parse the json data from a list to the details page, all product show the first product details in the details page.

```
[1]: https://youtu.be/VOE33E2DHW8
```

```
Details Page

Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 420.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(viewDetails.type[0].pic),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  viewDetails.type[0].name,
                  style: kCardText,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try use `ListView` with it's `Builder`:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: viewDetails.type.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final type = viewDetails.type[index];
    return Text(
      type.name,
      style: kCardText,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    );
  }
);
```

Also, more information about `ListView` contains in [Official Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).

Comment: Works great, however when I click an item on the list, its shows all products in one item on the list. I think am messing up an index somewhere. [link](https://youtu.be/tfE5j-qfnx8)

Comment: Can you show how do you handling click on item?

Comment: I have used a ListView. builder that returns a GestureDetector that has wrapped a Card with ListTile children. [Link](https://paemark.co.ke/List/2A.jpg)

Comment: Maybe while am passing the viewDetails from the viewList to the DrinkDetails() page, I could be mission something.

Comment: The DinkDetails() [Link](https://paemark.co.ke/List/DrinkDetails.jpg)

Comment: You passed to new screen all items in collection, not selected item.

Comment: how would you go about it?

Comment: You should pass selected item to screen that display selected item info.

Comment: Thank you very much Fartem, I finally got it. I appreciate your assistance